# Determine if any value in an array is anywhere inside a cell

Tags: arrays, search, find, substring, excel-2010

**GOAL**
Check anywhere within a cell to see if one of six letter combinations exists. If it does, display "nonprod", otherwise display "prod".

**BACKGROUND**
I have 1,735 computer names with all sorts of different naming conventions, but they all have one thing in common: the identification of the environment where they operate. The abbreviations of the environments within the server names are "dev", "stg", "qa", "tst", "lt", or "prf". The computer names are in a column called "Host" ($A:$A) and look like this: csap-dev01 (a "dev" server), cssp-qa01 (a "qa" server), cstg-stg-ps-01 (a "stg" server), etc. Sometimes the host names don't fit any of these naming conventions, in which case they are assumed to be "prod" servers.

**MY SOLUTION**
In a column called "Lifecycle", I created a formula to check if the host name contains any of the Lifecycle values. It if does, then the cell should display "nonprod", otherwise, it should display "prod".

=IF(ISERROR(FIND("lt",$A403,5)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("prf",$A403,5)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("tst",$A403,5)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("qa",$A403,5)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("stg",$A403,5)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("dev",$A403,5)),"prod","nonprod"),"nonprod"),"nonprod"),"nonprod"),"nonprod"),"nonprod").

**ERRORS WITH FIND**
When I saw that the FIND function will also use an array of values, I shortened the formula to  =IF(ISERROR(FIND(Lifecycle,$A403)),"prod","nonprod"), but it always returns #VALUE!. I've just tried a basic FIND like this, =FIND(Lifecycle,$A403), and it only works if "dev" is in the name, otherwise it returns #VALUE!.

**YOUR HELP**
I could sure use your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question as no `?` so I'm not sure what you are after but a shorter version than your formula that works might be:

```
=IF(SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(NPlist,A403),0),1))>0,"nonprod","prod")
```

where NPlist is a Defined Name for your server name environment abbreviations.

It is an array formula so requires entry with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.